# Zoom to fit Force layout in D3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following Force layout graph in my D3 code...

```js
// Code goes here

var width = w = 300,
  height = h = 300,
  link,
  node,
  svg,
  force,
  drag,
  currentSelected;

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}

var graph = {
 "nodes": 
 [
  {
   "code": "1130",
   "name": "Interior",
   "title": "Interior",
   "id": 137,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "50",
   "name": "Loose Equipment",
   "title": "Loose Equipment",
   "id": 146,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2781 ",
   "name": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "title": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "id": 218,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2830 ",
   "name": "FUEL DUMP",
   "title": "FUEL DUMP",
   "id": 227,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },
      {
   "code": "1130",
   "name": "Interior",
   "title": "Interior",
   "id": 138,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "50",
   "name": "Loose Equipment",
   "title": "Loose Equipment",
   "id": 147,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2781 ",
   "name": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "title": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "id": 219,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2830 ",
   "name": "FUEL DUMP",
   "title": "FUEL DUMP",
   "id": 228,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },
      {
   "code": "1130",
   "name": "Interior",
   "title": "Interior",
   "id": 139,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "50",
   "name": "Loose Equipment",
   "title": "Loose Equipment",
   "id": 148,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2781 ",
   "name": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "title": "LE FLAP POSITION IND SYSTEM",
   "id": 220,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  },

  {
   "code": "2830 ",
   "name": "FUEL DUMP",
   "title": "FUEL DUMP",
   "id": 229,
   "label": "ATAChild"
  }
 ],

 "links": 
 [
  
 ]
}

function render() {
    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .call(drag);
}

function init() {
  force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

  svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
  drag = force.drag();
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");
  node = svg.selectAll(".node");
}

window.onload = function(){
  init();
  render();
}
```

```html
<div id="graph" class="full"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now I am fairly new to D3 but as you can see my issue is that you cannot see all the nodes. I am not sure what is happening here but I would like to have it zoom out so that even if it is painfully small I can still see all nodes. I have seen some answers related to zooming but I have had no luck getting it to work with the force layout. Im you need to play around I have a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZomUBTXn6anauE2hfFl?p=preview) as well.

Comment: this version zooms in but not out... almost there...

http://plnkr.co/edit/1A11aXGBE0RPB0lC4jgA?p=preview

Comment: Changing to a lower number (example .1) in the zoom works but how do I default there?

Comment: Almost got it the last thing left is to know what I need to put into the transform to get it to the center.

Comment: Haha I guess I am going to figure this out on my own (check the previous plnkr) last thing is to avoid the jump when you first zoom

Comment: You'd have to compute the extent of the x and y coordinates and set a zoom factor that scales this extent to the size of your canvas.